# How to use Firefox concurrently

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to use `Firefox` with the same preferences in two or more different computers? I am currently using `Windows` and sometimes switch to `Linux`. My all bookmarks and other savings are stored in Windows profile. How can I use them together so that when I make a change on one profile, it will immediately change the other one, too. Therefore, I will always use the same preferences and does not have to move the profiles between two OS all the time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox options you can create a SYNC account, you should try it.

Comment: I have failed to use Sync before but now I managed and it worked. Thank you very much